# How to do window function inside a when?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, window

I have a dataframe where I am trying to do window function on a array column.

The logic is as follows: Group by (or window partition) the `id` and `filtered` columns. Calculate the max score of the rows where the `types` column is null, otherwise take the score of that row. When score is not equal to the max score of the group add "NA" to the column type.

```
val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, "shirt for women", Seq("shirt", "women"), 19.1, "ST"),
  (1, "shirt for women", Seq("shirt", "women"), 10.1, null),
  (1, "shirt for women", Seq("shirt", "women"), 12.1, null),
  (0, "shirt group women", Seq("group", "women"), 15.1, null),
  (0, "shirt group women", Seq("group", "women"), 12.1, null),
  (3, "shirt nmn women", Seq("shirt", "women"), 16.1, "ST"),
  (3, "shirt were women", Seq("shirt", "women"), 13.1, "ST")
)).toDF("id", "raw", "filtered", "score", "types")

  +---+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+
|id |raw              |filtered      |score|types|
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|19.1 |ST   |
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|10.1 |null |
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|12.1 |null |
|0  |shirt group women|[group, women]|15.1 |null |
|0  |shirt group women|[group, women]|12.1 |null |
|3  |shirt nmn women  |[shirt, women]|16.1 |ST   |
|3  |shirt were women |[shirt, women]|13.1 |ST   |
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+
```

Expected output:

```
   +---+------------------+--------------+-----+----+
    |id |raw              |filtered      |score|types|
    +---+-----------------+--------------+-----+----+
    |1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|19.1 |ST  |
    |1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|10.1 |NA  |
    |1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|12.1 |null|
    |0  |shirt group women[women, group] |15.1 |null|
    |0  |shirt group women|[women, group]|12.1 |NA  |
    |3  |shirt nmn women  |[shirt, women]|16.1 |ST  |
    |3  |shirt were women |[shirt, women]|13.1 |ST  |
    +---+-----------------+--------------+-----+----+
```

I tried:

```
data.withColumn("max_score",
      when(col("types").isNull,
        max("score")
          .over(Window.partitionBy("id", "filtered")))
        .otherwise($"score"))
      .withColumn("type_temp",
        when(col("score") =!= col("max_score"),
          addReasonsUDF(col("type"),
            lit("NA")))
          .otherwise(col("type")))
      .drop("types", "max_score")
      .withColumnRenamed("type_temp", "types")
```

But it is not working. This gives me:

```
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+---------+-----+
|id |raw              |filtered      |score|max_score|types|
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+---------+-----+
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|19.1 |19.1     |ST   |
|1  |shirt women      |[shirt, women]|10.1 |19.1     |NA   |
|1  |shirt of women   |[shirt, women]|12.1 |19.1     |NA   |
|0  |shirt group women|[group, women]|15.1 |15.1     |null |
|0  |shirt will women |[group, women]|12.1 |15.1     |NA   |
|3  |shirt nmn women  |[shirt, women]|16.1 |16.1     |ST   |
|3  |shirt were women |[shirt, women]|13.1 |13.1     |ST   |
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+---------+-----+
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

I think something wrong with my window function, when I tried partition against `id` and `raw` its not working as well. So both string and array partitions are not working.

```
dataSet.withColumn("max_score",
      when(col("types").isNull,
        max("score").over(Window.partitionBy("id", "raw")))
        .otherwise($"score")).show(false)

+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+---------+
|id |raw              |filtered      |score|types|max_score|
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+---------+
|3  |shirt nmn women  |[shirt, women]|16.1 |ST   |16.1     |
|0  |shirt group women|[group, women]|15.1 |null |15.1     |
|0  |shirt group women|[group, women]|12.1 |null |15.1     |
|3  |shirt were women |[shirt, women]|13.1 |ST   |13.1     |
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|19.1 |ST   |19.1     |
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|10.1 |null |19.1     |
|1  |shirt for women  |[shirt, women]|12.1 |null |19.1     |
+---+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to have a window function inside a `when` expression, instead this can be done in two stages. First add the max score as a new column to each group based on the `id`, `filtered` **and the `types` columns**. This will give a max score specifically for the groups where `types` are `null`. A window expression is preferred for this since the other columns should be kept.

After this, a check with `when`/`otherwise` can be done to change the value of the `types` column as long as `types` have a `null` value and the max score is not equal to `score`.

In code:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("id", "filtered", "types")
val df = data.withColumn("max_score", max($"score").over(w))
  .withColumn("types", when($"types".isNull && $"score" =!= $"max_score", "NA").otherwise($"types"))
  .drop("max_score")
```

Comment: The issue is types can be different for the group (id, filtered) I can't use that to group by

Comment: @user3407267: That doesn't matter. Only the max score calculated for the groups where types is null are used in the end. The result should be identical to your expected output.

Comment: 1 thing I noticed is, the array should be same order (I can do sorted) but is there a way to partition by irrespective of array order ? Just curious

Comment: @user3407267: I don't think there is a direct way of doing that. But you could always sort it again just to be sure, just use `sort_array`.