# How to remove elements from an array Column in Spark?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, seq

I have a `Seq` and dataframe. The dataframe contains a column of array type. I am trying to remove the elements that are in the `Seq` from the column.

For example:

```
val stop_words = Seq("a", "and", "for", "in", "of", "on", "the", "with", "s", "t")

    +---------------------------------------------------+
    |sorted_items                                       |
    +---------------------------------------------------+
    |[flannel, and, for, s, shirts, sleeve, warm]       |
    |[3, 5, kitchenaid, s]                              |
    |[5, 6, case, flip, inch, iphone, on, xs]           |
    |[almonds, chocolate, covered, dark, joe, s, the]   |
    |null                                               |
    |[]                                                 |
    |[animation, book]                                  |
```

Expected output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|sorted_items                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|[flannel, shirts, sleeve, warm]                    |
|[3, 5, kitchenaid]                                 |
|[5, 6, case, flip, inch, iphone, xs]               |
|[almonds, chocolate, covered, dark, joe, the]      |
|null                                               |
|[]                                                 |
|[animation, book]                                  |
```

How can this be done in an effective and optimized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`StopWordsRemover`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stopwordsremover) from the MLlib package. It is possible to set custom stop words using the `setStopWords` function. `StopWordsRemover` will not handle null values so those will need to be dealt with before usage. It can be done as follows:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("sorted_values", coalesce($"sorted_values", array()))

val remover = new StopWordsRemover()
  .setStopWords(stop_words.toArray)
  .setInputCol("sorted_values")
  .setOutputCol("filtered")

val df3 = remover.transform(df2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179275/scala-spark-how-to-do-window-function-inside-a-when If you what I am doing wrong here. Please let me know

Answer (score 8):

Use `array_except` from `spark.sql.functions`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}

val stopWords = Array("a", "and", "for", "in", "of", "on", "the", "with", "s", "t")

val newDF = df.withColumn("sorted_items", F.array_except(df("sorted_items"), F.lit(stopWords)))

newDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|sorted_items                            |
+----------------------------------------+
|[flannel, shirts, sleeve, warm]         |
|[3, 5, kitchenaid]                      |
|[5, 6, case, flip, inch, iphone, xs]    |
|[almonds, chocolate, covered, dark, joe]|
|null                                    |
|[]                                      |
|[animation, book]                       |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How can this be translated into SQL?